# Help me understand Z coefficients

Tags: sample-size, descriptive-statistics

When working with sample size equations, one uses the Z coefficients *Z<sub>$\alpha$</sub>* and *Z<sub>$\beta$</sub>* which are the Z-coefficient for Type I and Type II error rates. These coefficients are from the standard normal distribution.

Does it matter if the data you're working with aren't normally distributed? Specifically, I'm working with vegetation data that are beta-distributed. Do I need to use coefficients for a different distribution, or is this not related to the sampled data?

Comment: What are these values supposed to tell you? How are they used? How are they calculated?

Comment: The key to the answer lies in the [sampling distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sampling+distribution) of your test statistic, which is almost always (very) different from the data distribution.  If that's an unfamiliar term or concept, follow the link.